# Non Static variable count getting accessed from static method?

Tags: java

How does non static variable count gets accessed from static main method here.I was expecting an error. Compiler should throw an error. Correct me if am wrong 
Non static members cannot be accessed from static context

```
class sync {

  private int count;
  public static void main (String args[]) {

    sync obj =new sync();
    obj.do();
  }

  public void do() {

    Thread t =new Thread(new Runnable () {

      public void run() {
        for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    });

    Thread t1=new Thread (new Runnable () {

      public void run () {
        for(int i=0;i<=1000;i++) {
          count++;
        }
      }
    });

    t.start();
    t1.start();
    System.out.println(count) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does `count` get accessed from a `static` method? `do` is not `static`... As an aside; in Java we **always** use `PascalCase` for classes - `Sync` is a class, `sync` is not.

Comment: P.S. as `count` is not protected by a lock, and is not `volatile`, the result of the code is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

It is not being accessed within the static method.

In the places it is being accessed, it is not accessed in a static context, but through an instance of sync.

```
public static void main(String[] a){
  int a = count; // this would be wrong, and cause the error you expect
}

public static void main(String[] a){
  sync a = new sync();
  int b = a.getCount(); // or even a.count; for a public variable
  // is valid, since even though it is within a static method, it is not in 
  // a static context
}
```